# How to find instance of a bound method in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
>>> class A(object):  
...         def some(self):  
...                 pass  
...  
>>> a=A()  
>>> a.some  
<bound method A.some of <__main__.A object at 0x7f0d6fb9c090>>
```

IOW, I need to get access to "a" after being handed over only "a.some".

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Starting python 2.6 you can use special attribute `__self__`:

```
>>> a.some.__self__ is a
True
```

`im_self` is phased out in py3k.

For details, see the [`inspect` module in the Python Standard Library.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)

Comment: Just to make it entirely clear: Use this if you have Python 3. If you're using Python 2, the equivalent is the `im_self` that others have posted.

Comment: This does not appear to work for dunder methods, e.g. in the original example, `A().__init__.__self__` and `A().__eq__.__self__` do not exist. Any idea if there is an alternative?

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def some(self):
...     pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x7fa9b965f410>
>>> a.some
<bound method A.some of <__main__.A object at 0x7fa9b965f410>>
>>> dir(a.some)
['__call__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__func__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'im_class', 'im_func', 'im_self']
>>> a.some.im_self
<__main__.A object at 0x7fa9b965f410>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following code and see, if it helps you:

```
a.some.im_self
```

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this I guess:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> m = a.some
>>> another_obj = m.im_self
>>> another_obj
<__main__.A object at 0x0000000002818320>
```

`im_self` is the class instance object.