# Can't read full text of nose.test assertion error

Tags: python, python-unittest, nose

I'm writing tests in python using unittest.

One test fails, and I can't understand why. The error is truncated, where it says `[46chars]` and `[493 chars]`. It would be very helpful to be able to see the full text of the statement. Is that possible?

This is error:

```
nose.proxy.AssertionError: [call[46 chars]24.0)] != [call[46chars]24.0),
call(None, 'cluster.ec2-test-cluster1.[493 chars]4.0)]
```

This is the test:

```
expected = [call(None, 'cluster.ec2-test-cluster1.age.lower', 24.0)]
self.assertEqual(expected, my_mock.call_args_list)
```

Comment: I finally found the answer in another stack question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493670/how-to-set-self-maxdiff-in-nose-to-get-full-diff-output/