# How do I get PyCharm to show entire error diffs from pytest?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest, difference

I am using [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to run my [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) unit tests. I am testing a REST API, so I often have to validate blocks of JSON. When a test fails, I'll see something like this:

```
FAILED
test_document_api.py:0 (test_create_documents)
{'items': [{'i...ages': 1, ...} != {'items': [{'...ages': 1, ...}

Expected :{'items': [{'...ages': 1, ...}
Actual   :{'items': [{'i...ages': 1, ...}
 <Click to see difference>
```

When I click on the "Click to see difference" link, most of the difference is converted to points of ellipses, like so

[image: Pycharm comparison with differences elided]

This is useless since it doesn't show me what is different. I get this behavior for any difference larger than a single string or number.

I assume Pycharm and/or pytest tries to elide uninformative parts of differences for large outputs. However, it's being too aggressive here and eliding everything.

How do I get Pycharm and/or pytest to show me the entire difference?

I've tried adding `-vvv` to pytest's Additional Arguments, but that has no effect.

---

Since the original post I verified that I see the same behavior when I run unit tests from the command line. So this is an issue with pytest and not Pycharm.

After looking at the answers I've got so far I guess what I'm really asking is "in pytest is it possible to set `maxDiff=None` without changing the source code of your tests?" The impression I've gotten from reading about pytest is that the `-vv` switch is what controls this setting, but this does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[If you look closely into PyCharm sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/teamcity/pytest_plugin.py#L259-L272), from the whole `pytest` output, PyCharm uses a single line the to parse the data for displaying in the `Click to see difference` dialog. This is the `AssertionError: <message>` line:

```
def test_spam():
>       assert v1 == v2
E       AssertionError: assert {'foo': 'bar'} == {'foo': 'baz'}
E         Differing items:
E         {'foo': 'bar'} != {'foo': 'baz'}
E         Use -v to get the full diff
```

If you want to see the full diff line without truncation, you need to customize this line in the output. For a single test, this can be done by adding a custom message to the `assert` statement:

```
def test_eggs():
    assert a == b, '{0} != {1}'.format(a, b)
```

If you want to apply this behaviour to all tests, define custom [`pytest_assertrepr_compare`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertrepr_compare) hook. In the `conftest.py` file:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(config, op, left, right):
    if op in ('==', '!='):
        return ['{0} {1} {2}'.format(left, op, right)]
```

The equality comparison of the values will now still be stripped when too long; to show the complete line, you still need to increase the verbosity with `-vv` flag.

Now the equality comparison of the values in the `AssertionError` line will not be stripped and the full diff is displayed in the `Click to see difference` dialog, highlighting the diff parts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went ahead and make a pull request: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/pull/1091

Comment: @Ilya Did you follow up jetbrain comment and forward PR to teamcity-messages ?

Comment: @AdrienH yes, it was merged: https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-messages/pull/210 -- should be fixed in latest PyCharm

Answer (score 4):

Being that pytest integrates with unittest, as a workaround you may be able to set it up as a unittest and then set `Test.maxDiff = None` or per each specific test `self.maxDiff = None`

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html

> Can run unittest (including trial) and nose test suites out of the box;

These may be helpful as well...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21615720/9530790

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23617918/9530790

Answer (score 1):

Had a look in the pytest code base and maybe you can try some of these out:

1) Set verbosity level in the test execution:

```
./app_main --pytest --verbose test-suite/
```

2) Add environment variable for "CI" or "BUILD_NUMBER". In the link to
   the truncate file you can see that these env variables are used to
   determine whether or not the truncation block is run.

```
import os

os.environ["BUILD_NUMBER"] = '1'
os.environ["CI"] = 'CI_BUILD'
```

3) Attempt to set DEFAULT_MAX_LINES and DEFAULT_MAX_CHARS on the truncate module (**Not recommending this since it uses a private module**):

```
from _pytest.assertion import truncate

truncate.DEFAULT_MAX_CHARS = 1000
truncate.DEFAULT_MAX_LINES = 1000
```

According to the code the -vv option should work so it's strange that it's not for you:

> Current default behaviour is to truncate assertion explanations at
>   ~8 terminal lines, unless running in "-vv" mode or running on CI.

Pytest truncation file which are what I'm basing my answers off of: [pytest/truncate.py](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/assertion/truncate.py)

Hope something here helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I have some getattr in assertion and it never shows anything after `AssertionError`.

I add `-lv` in the `Additional Arguments` field to show the local variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into something similar and created a function that returns a string with a nice diff of the two `dicts`.  In `pytest` style test this looks like:

```
assert expected == actual, build_diff_string(expected, actual)
```

And in `unittest` style

```
self.assertEqual(expected, actual, build_diff_string(expected, actual)
```

The downside is that you have to modify the all the tests that have this issue, but it's a Keep It Simple and Stupid solution.

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm you can just put -vv in the run configuration Additional Arguments field and this should solve the issue.

Or at least, it worked on my machine...