# How to get name of class if I know only a bound method in python?

Tags: python, oop, classname

In pyton code I've got a bound method of some object. Knowing only this bound method I would like to know what is the class of that object. Is it possible?

Here is sample code:

```
>>> class x:
...     def method(self):
...             pass
...
>>> x
<class __main__.x at 0xb737d1ac> 
>>> x_instance = x()
>>> x_instance
<__main__.x instance at 0xb737c7cc>
>>> boundmethod = x_instance.method
>>> boundmethod
<bound method x.method of <__main__.x instance at 0xb737c7cc>>
>>> str(boundmethod)
'<bound method x.method of <__main__.x instance at 0xb737c7cc>>'
```

Let's assume I know only `boundmethod`. How to determine that the class is `x`?

Comment: After taking a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679592/how-to-find-instance-of-a-bound-method-in-python) question I know i could do sth like `boundmethod.im_self.__class__.__name__`. Is there any easier way?

Comment: Why would there be an easier way? Why are you passing around bound methods instead of the objects they are bound to?

Comment: And looking at jamylak comment I finally found the solution: `boundmethod.im_class.__name__`. Thanks.

Comment: @running.t try a `dir(...)`  next time, since you were so close you would have found it had you done that

Comment: @Wooble: bound methods are first class citizens in the Python world and there are very obvious reasons to "pass around" bound methods instead of instances - like, say, as a callback... 
Now I agree that except for 1/ debugging and 2/ a very few corner cases I don't see much reason to try and find the class of the bound instance.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Indeed that was for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the name of it:

```
boundmethod.im_class.__name__
```

Or in python 3:

```
boundmethod.__self__.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Hello - just looking for some clarification; if `boundmethod` is attached to an instance that has an inheritance hierarchy, and `boundmethod` exists towards the bottom of that hierarchy, will `boundmethod.im_class` point to the class that defined it, or will it point to `boundmethod`'s class?

Comment: @GershomMaes I believe it should point to `boundmethod`'s class If I've interpreted you correctly